# Is there a way I can process the combined output of multiple commands at once, using xargs?

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs

I have multiple shell commands that I want to pipe into the same `xargs` instance so I can process them together.

I have two inputs, a file and a glob expression:

```bsh
$ cat subdomains.txt 

admin.site.com
web.site.com
api.site.com

$ ls -d x*

xab  xac  xad
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
admin.site.com:xab
admin.site.com:xac
admin.site.com:xad
web.site.com:xab
web.site.com:xac
web.site.com:xad
api.site.com:xab
api.site.com:xac
api.site.com:xad
```

Here's the command I tried (which doesn't work):

```bsh
cat subdomains.txt |  ls -d x* | xargs -I value1,value2 echo 'value1:value2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with GNU `parallel`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' x* | parallel echo "{1}:{2}" :::: subdomains.txt :::: -
admin.site.com:xab
admin.site.com:xac
admin.site.com:xad
web.site.com:xab
web.site.com:xac
web.site.com:xad
api.site.com:xab
api.site.com:xac
api.site.com:xad
```

Comment: If I want to execute command instead of echo ? what should I do? 

ex: I want to run mytool.sh --parm1 {1} --parm2 {2}

**Does it work in this way?** 

```shell

printf '%s\n' x* | parallel mytool.sh --parm1 {1} --parm2 {2} :::: subdomains.txt :::: -

```

Comment: @AtikRahman yes that should work I think...

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to push input into my tools. Any way to do it via xargs ? 
thanks anyway.

Comment: @AtikRahman what happens, exactly, when you try?

Comment: It throws an error that input of both {1} and {2} cannot found.

Comment: @AtikRahman what is `shell` in your comment above? are you actually executing this in an interactive shell, or is it some kind of container?

Answer (score 1):

An ugly method: `eval` is needed because brace expansion normally happens before variable expansion, so we require 2 rounds of evaluation.

```bsh
sub=$( paste -sd, subdomains.txt )
xs=$( ls -d x* | paste -sd, )
eval "printf '%s\n' {$sub}:{$xs}"
```

better: store the result of each individual step in arrays, then have  nested loops to combine them.

```bsh
mapfile -t sub < subdomains.txt
xs=( x* )
for s in "${sub[@]}"; do
  for x in "${xs[@]}"; do
    echo "$s:$x"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '%s\n' x* | join -t : -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1 subdomains.txt -
admin.site.com:xaa
admin.site.com:xab
admin.site.com:xac
web.site.com:xaa
web.site.com:xab
web.site.com:xac
api.site.com:xaa
api.site.com:xab
api.site.com:xac
```

This uses `join` to produce a sort of cross product between the domains listed in the file `subdomains.txt` and the filenames starting with the character `x` in the current directory.

The cross product is produce by asking `join` to join the two data sets on a non-existing field (column 2, specified with `-1 2` and `-2 2`). We also specify the input and output field delimiter as `:` with `-t :`, and we explicitly ask to to get the first column from each file using `-o 1.1,2.1` (or we would have had an empty first column in the result).

Answer (score 0):

You only need `printf '%s\n' x*` if you have more than 32000 files.

Otherwise this will work:

```
parallel mytool.sh --parm1 {1} --parm2 {2} :::: subdomains.txt ::: x*
```

Read chapter 1+2 of http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html (can be downloaded at https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014). Your command line will love you for it.

(If the `x*` files are from `split` you should also read chapter 9

```
parallel -a bigfile --block 10M --pipepart --argsep ,, -I ,, parallel --pipe --tee wc {} ::: -l -c -w
```

).

Comment: The number "32000" depends on the Unix, and on the size of the current environment.